# Less when including files with relative paths

Tags: css, less

I have the following less files:

**WebApp/Content/less/main.less**

```
@import "src/test.less";
```

**WebApp/Content/less/src/test.less:**

```
body { 
     background-image: url("../img/abc.png");
}
```

When I run less 1.3.0 via less.js-windows

**> less.js-windows\lessc.cmd WebApp\Content\less WebApp\Content\css  -compress**

... I get this:

```
body{background-image:url("src/src/../img/abc.png");}
```

The "src/src/.." doesn't look correct to me.

I spent about an hour on it but I can't determine the status of this problem from the less project from its github page.  There are numerous issues, regressions, and applied and unapplied pull requests which appear to address it:  https://github.com/cloudhead/less.js/issues/search?q=relative.

I can't use absolute paths in this case.  Is there a simple fix or a workaround for this issue?

Comment: Try dotless, its a port.that I believe has these issues fixed, plus an option to turn off url rewriting.

Comment: Worked perfectly, thanks!  I see it exposes a "-disable-url-rewriting" flag which less.js-windows doesn't have.

Answer (score 1):

Do the following:

```
body
{
    background-image : ~"url( '../img/abc.png' )";
}
```